# Software/IDE for Application development in Symbian OS

Tags: windows-7, software-development, ide

I am thinking about developing apps for Symbian OS. I know what you are thinking right now. You must be thinking I am insane.

Symbian OS is of no value now as Nokia stopped development. There are lot of users who are still using the good old Symbian OS phones.

I am looking for an IDE or software or whatever that can help me in this. Links to tutorials or anything that is useful.

I heard about Symbian Analysis Workbench (SAW) but didn't find any download links for it. Can anyone help me.
I am using a Windows 7 desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `Visual Studio 2008`.

It is possible to create `Silverlight-Based` apps for `Symbian S60` series with `C#` language in Visual Studio 2008.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770308(v=vs.95).aspx) for more info and a step-by-step starter.